# Is there any documentation on StringTemplates in Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I recently learnt to create custom helpers and i came across the following lines of code in the helper docs:

```
use StringTemplateTrait;

protected $_defaultConfig = [
    'errorClass' => 'error',
    'templates' => [
        'label' => '<label for="{{for}}">{{content}}</label>',
    ],
];
```

(I don't know how to use this template yet)

What i want to do is to develop a **MenusHelper** that will take up an array of nested children and will create a multilevel menu. But I want it to be flexible enough so users can add custom html before and after the "**ul**'s"  and "**li**'s".

I searched for [StringTemplate](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.StringTemplate.html) & [StringTemplateTrait](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.StringTemplateTrait.html) but did not get anything else other than just the api guide.

So I have these question is mind:

1. Am i looking for the right thing?
2. If yes, Where can i get more help to understand these concepts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you're looking something like [this](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig). This is a list of all `default` form tags templates which are used in CakePHP 3.

See also [list of templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#list-of-templates) chapter from `Form Helper` documentation.

Comment: I was asking in general not just related to Forms. But it was very helpful understanding the concept. Thanks.